# reboot raspberry if python script stop with error

Tags: linux, python-3.x, python-2.7, raspberry-pi3

I use a Python script on a raspberry that communicates with the Internet and USB with an Arduino and it happens that one of the 2 communications blow because of some error, and I would like in case this file python stops because of an error that the Raspberry restarts ! can some one hepl me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a solution to restart the Pi. You will have to check for your error first. That can be done using a try/except construction:

```
import os
try:
    <<your code here>>
except:
    os.system("sudo reboot") # reboots the pi
```

Comment: thanks for your answer ! i have this error :                                                                                                 Max retries exceeded with url: /post (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x0000019E893F8A90>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed',)) !! i havn't the name of the error

Comment: @jawaddidouh Technically you could put all your code in one try/except statement. But this will catch every error and making it hard to debug. If you know where your error happens put that piece of Code into "try" and catch only your specific error using "except ConnectionError:"